# Look up Swift assembler in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, assembly, disassembly

When coding in C/C++/Objective-C in Xcode I can use `Product > Perform Action > Assemble "file.c"` to view this file assembler result. But this action is always disabled for `.swift` files. Why so?

How can I inspect assembler produced by Swift complier? Doesn't Xcode have this functionality yet? What are the other options?

I'm interested in generated assembler for inspecting high performance tight loops in my own code.

Comment: Not sure about Xcode, but for other options: https://godbolt.org

Comment: @jnpdx: godbolt *has* Swift as an option in the language dropdown: https://godbolt.org/z/KMch8bd8E - it uses `swiftc` whose asm output looks like LLVM.